# NEXTjs 13 SSR doesnt work with Link component reentering once visited path

Tags: layout, server-side-rendering, isr, next.js13

SSR does work ONLY when u manually/hard refresh the page and not when u navigating back and forward with Link component from next/link...(with Link component - entering the (page / path / segment) first time will SSR, but reentering the same page/path SSR doesnt work anymore) This hurts me so much. How do we solve this?

PS. To activate the SSR I have tested all variants.

On segment (layout / page) level:

1. export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
2. export const revalidate = 0
3. export const fetchCache = 'force-no-store'

on .fetch() options level:

1. {cache: 'no-store'}
2. {next: {revalidate: 0}}
3. {
   cache: 'no-store',
   next: {revalidate: 0}
   }

So whats the problem? SSR should fetch against DB EACH time path changes to render the page with new content. Or am i wrong?

Comment: Replied on possible duplicate with workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75688590/9476735

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is related to client-side [Hydration](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hydrate), to fix the issue you can try the [prefetch](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link#prefetch) prop in the `Link` component:

```
<Link href="/about" prefetch>
   About
</Link>
```